# Gathering attendance list with python re.findall

Tags: python

Here we have a zoom chat history from which I would like to **extract all of the student ID**, for example, 38150002, and **the name of the ID owner** (e.g. smith example).

```
17:00:44     From Smith Example : 38150002 Smith Example
17:00:54     From Smith Example : 41050002 Smith Middle Example
17:01:04     From Smith Example : 37-191129 Smith One Example
17:01:12     From Smith Example : 31-086612 Smith Example
17:01:20     From Smith Example : 40-250233 Smith Example
17:01:33     From Smith Example : 38129055 Smith Example
17:01:39     From Smith Example : 38-129055 Smith Example Joe
```

I succeed to extract the student id with a set pattern with re.findall.

```
lst = re.findall('\d\d-\d+', ex) #for id like 40-250233
```

The question is **how can I extract the name** following the student id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the exact structure you gave, you can use this regex:

```
\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.*:\s*([\d-]+)\s*(.*)$
```

I put the ID and name in capture groups so using `findall` will give a nice result. For example:

```py
import re

s = """17:00:44     From Smith Example : 38150002 Smith Example\n
17:00:54     From Smith Example : 41050002 Smith Middle Example\n
17:01:04     From Smith Example : 37-191129 Smith One Example\n
17:01:12     From Smith Example : 31-086612 Smith Example\n
17:01:20     From Smith Example : 40-250233 Smith Example\n
17:01:33     From Smith Example : 38129055 Smith Example\n
17:01:39     From Smith Example : 38-129055 Smith Example Joe\n"""

print(re.findall(r'\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.*:\s*([\d-]+)\s*(.*)$', s, re.M))
```

will give:

```
[('38150002', 'Smith Example'), 
 ('41050002', 'Smith Middle Example'), 
 ('37-191129', 'Smith One Example'), 
 ('31-086612', 'Smith Example'), 
 ('40-250233', 'Smith Example'), 
 ('38129055', 'Smith Example'), 
 ('38-129055', 'Smith Example Joe')]
```

[Regex Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/fKmNQ3/1).

---

Note that if you are iterating a file line by line you don't need the [`re.M`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) flag.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to extract the ID **and** name (feel free to refine the name-matching regex `\w+(?:[ ]\w+)+` for better control):

```py
>>> re.findall('\d\d-\d+[ ]\w+(?:[ ]\w+)+', ex)
['37-191129 Smith One Example', '31-086612 Smith Example', '40-250233 Smith Example', '38-129055 Smith Example Joe']
```

If you **only** want the name, use the non-capturing group `(?:)` to omit the ID part and put the name in `()`:

```py
>>> re.findall('(?:\d\d-\d+)[ ](\w+(?:[ ]\w+)+)', ex)
['Smith One Example', 'Smith Example', 'Smith Example', 'Smith Example Joe']
```

BTW you can also capture ID and name as tuple:

```py
>>> re.findall('(\d\d-\d+)[ ](\w+(?:[ ]\w+)+)', ex)
[('37-191129', 'Smith One Example'), ('31-086612', 'Smith Example'), ('40-250233', 'Smith Example'), ('38-129055', 'Smith Example Joe')]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of ways, but here's an easy one using split and join, which assumes that:

1. Colons remain constant as separators in the file
2. Everything after the student ID refers to the student name

The code is as follows, applied to one row:

```
row_string = "17:00:44     From Smith Example : 38150002 Smith Example"
ID = row_string.split(':')[3].split(' ')[1] # '38150002'
name = " ".join(row_string.split(':')[3].split(' ')[2:]) #'Smith Example'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. 'Everything after the student ID refers to the student name' seems to be a very good way because different students tend to input their names in different patterns. With your answer, I could collect their name without worrying about how they input their names. (for example some people just don't put a space between first and last name)

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
ex='''17:00:44     From Smith Example : 38150002 Smith Example
17:00:54     From Smith Example : 41050002 Smith Middle Example
17:01:04     From Smith Example : 37-191129 Smith One Example
17:01:12     From Smith Example : 31-086612 Smith Example
17:01:20     From Smith Example : 40-250233 Smith Example
17:01:33     From Smith Example : 38129055 Smith Example
17:01:39     From Smith Example : 38-129055 Smith Example Joe'''

lst = re.findall(r'(:\s+)(\d{2}-\d+|\d+)([\s+\w+]+)', ex)

print(lst)
```

Ouput :

```
[(': ', '38150002', ' Smith Example\n17'), (': ', '41050002', ' Smith Middle Example\n17'), (': ', '37-191129', ' Smith One Example\n17'), (': ', '31-086612', ' Smith Example\n17'), (': ', '40-250233', ' Smith Example\n17'), (': ', '38129055', ' Smith Example\n17'), (': ', '38-129055', ' Smith Example Joe')]
```

Here you can get both patterns matched for the examples you have given .
The output basically contains 3 parts for each pattern matched - first part is `:` , second part is `ID` which is the 2 patterns you have given (if you want to match more patterns you should change the regex as per needs , cannot write a regex in generic way) , third part is `whole string after ID` (this also should be customized if you want to capture only upto 2nd space or 3rd space character)

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Your code doesn't return the full name associated with the ID- it just returns the last name. Also, you're not returning the IDs without hyphens.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I am just showing an example of using re.findall to gather all the IDs. But it is the names that confused me because students tend to input their names with different patterns.

Comment: i have updated .  should work for the patterns you have given .